# Match specific substring with string in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on ruby on rails project and I want to match specific substring with string suppose `part1_hello_part2`,`part3_hii_part4` this is 2 strings and I want to match with the substring `_hello_`

Items array:

```
[
    {
        id:1,
        name:part1_hello_part2,
    },{
        id:2,
        name:part3_hii_part4,
    }
    ...
    ...
    {
    }
]
for item in @items
  if item.name.to_s.match? /\b.*?_hello_.*?\b/
     @data.push item
  end
end
```

In the loop of items, I have strings with the name field if match with a specific substring then item push in the data variable. how can I do this?

Update: Actually I want to push the matched data`(*_hello_*)` in new array `@data` so I  use that in another process

Comment: Your regexp is just a complicated way to test, whether item.name.to_s contains a substring `_hello_`. From your question, it is not clear to me whether this is what you want.

Comment: What is the input, what is the expected output? What is `@data`? Do you really want to iterate the whole `@items`? Or do you want to select all matching records from that list and assign them to another variable?

Comment: @user1934428 I have updated my question please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what `@items` is. If it's an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, then you probably just want to use a query. If it's some other enumerable, like an `Array`...

`item in @items` isn't very rubyish, so you might consider:

```
@items.each do |item|
  if item.name.to_s.match? /\b.*?_hello_.*?\b/
     @data.push item
  end
end
```

But, `@data.push` suggests you're building an array, so you might consider:

```
@data = @items.each_with_object([]) do |item, to_return|
  if item.name.to_s.match? /\b.*?_hello_.*?\b/
     to_return.push item
  end
end
```

But, `each_with_object` is a long walk when you have `select`, so you might consider:

```
@data = @items.select do |item|
  item.name.to_s.match? /\b.*?_hello_.*?\b/
end
```

Now, you also have `include?`, so you might consider:

```
@data = @items.select do |item|
  item.name.to_s.include?('_hello_')
end
```

At that point, you might want to get it all onto one line, so you might consider:

```
@data = @items.select { |item| item.name.to_s.include?('_hello_')}
```

You might want to compact that a little more, so you might consider:

```
@data = @items.select { |item| item.name.to_s['_hello_'] }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have probably tried out already by yourself using irb,

```
'part1_hello_part2'.match? /\b.*?_hello_.*?\b/
```

returns *true*, so the problem is not the matching part (although you probably should have written it better as `.include?('_hello_')`, which looks - at least to me - simpler and easier to understand than your obscure regexp.

If the matching does not work, it means that the left side is not the string what you expect it to be. At the very least, you should output `item.name.to_s` for debugging purposes. You did not show what `@items` is. You only said that it is an Array and show a *printed representation* of its content, which is not the same as showing what the content really is. From the display, it looks like the array elements were hashes, but in this case, I would expect that the elements were accessed by `item[:name]`. But if ìtem`is not just a Hash, but an object which understands the` name` method, this is, of course, a correct usage.

Aside from this, and assuming that `@data` understands the method `push`, your code looks fine, and you need to ask more precisely, which of the statements you have posted, does not yield the expected outcome.